# Disable entire Azure storage account

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, storage, account

Is it possible to disable the entire storage account using az cli? I looked through all properties for a storage account and couldn't find anything related to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to stop any action from being committed to the storage account resource? If so, and if you are an owner, you can enable the "Read-Only" resource lock so the resource cannot be modified in any way, including uploads of data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#considerations-before-applying-your-locks

Comment: The purpose here is to totally disable the storage account.
I'm working on storage account decommissioning automation for a large company who has mass number of azure resources. Before we delete the storage account, we want to totally disable it and see if there is anyone complains in 30 days. To disable it, I mean the user cannot even read any data from any form of the storage: containers, shares, queues and tables, even from azure web portal.

Comment: I don't believe there is a one-liner that'll do that for you. You'd probably have to rotate the keys to invalidate any SAS tokens and remove all RBAC permissions bar your own or a subset of accounts so that no-one can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable the entire storage account using az cli?

AFAIK, There is no direct command to disable the entire storage account using Azure CLI.

I agree with both acrophat's and Anthony Norwood's comments.

- First, you need to remove all RBAC permissions except yours or a subset of your accounts so that no one may access it.
- To invalidate any SAS tokens, you would probably have to rotate the keys.
- Another thing is to disable the networking.

You can use the below command to disable networking.

**Command:**

```
az storage account update --name MyStorageAccount --resource-group MyResourceGroup --public-network-access Disabled
```

**Output:**

```
"provisioningState": "Succeeded",
 "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
```

**Portal:**
[image]

Now users like **`reader`** role can't able to read the files.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Thank you!
I’m wondering if it is still accessible from any private endpoint if configured any. Should I remove all private endpoints as well?

Comment: Yeah.you can remove those.

Comment: How to remove RBAC permissions with cli commands?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-remove  You can use this document.

Comment: Great, thank you!!